# Scala: Post method is not working with list

Tags: scala

My Main Post Call which takes list of ids

```
} ~ (post & pathPrefix("all")) {
              authorize(user.admin.getOrElse(false)) {
                entity(as[List[String]]) { ids =>
                  complete(getAllUsers(ids))
                }
              }
            }
```

My JDBC class for above thing

```
 override def getAllUsers(ids: List[String]): Future[Iterable[User]] = Future {
    val u = UserWrapper.syntax
    val n = NotificationChannelWrapper.syntax
    withSQL {
      select.from(UserWrapper as u)
        .leftJoin(NotificationChannelWrapper as n)
        .on(u.id, n.field("userId"))
        .where.in(u.id, ids)
    }.one(UserWrapper(u.resultName)(_))
      .toMany(NotificationChannelWrapper.opt(n)(_))
      .map { (user, channels) => user.copy(notificationChannels = channels.toSet) }
      .fetchSize(1000)
      .list().apply()
  }
```

When I pass a multiply list of ids it won't take Can anyone please suggest where is the mistake.

Getting an error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass body without "id" fields, just simply passing list of strings like:

```
["first str", "second str"]
```

or if it's required to use format `{"id": "..."}` you need to create or use existing case class like:

```
case class Foo(id: String)
```

with converter for it from Json and accept entity of type `List[Foo]` instead of `List[String]`